# Home screen shortcut

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I often navigate in way too deep. Then to return to the home screen I have to swipe back like a maniac. Double-clicking title bar or something similar to take us directly to home would be nice. If such shortcut already exists I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Such a navigation gesture is not found in other iOS apps (of which some certainly suffer from the same problem as you describe). It is never a good idea to introduce such 'obscure' gestures. Especially when there's already an alternative: click the 'More' link below a question, and choose 'Switch to site' from the menu. This will bring you back to the 'root' level of a site, and from there you can access the hamburger menu to get to the home screen.

[image]

Comment: When I click *More* below the question I get the following three options: *Flag*, *Open in Safari*, and *Cancel*. There is not a *Switch to Site* option. (I am using iOS 9 but the apps are all updated in case that matters.)

Comment: Apparently, if I open a post from the history or from a question list I do get the *Switch to Site*. But if I search for something and then open one of the results, it no longer appears. In my case, I opened SO and searched for `[alloy]` and then selected one of the questions; in this case, the menu entry you mentioned does not appear.

Comment: No, because you're already on SO then. It is only shown if you are 'deep enough' in the app.